# Visual Studio Add Installer For Service Missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I've created windows services in the past no problem but I am now using a new setup at a new company and this is the first service I've created since then and I cannot add the installer option for it.  When I view the service in the designer and right click the design surface there is no "Add Installer" or "Create Installer" option

I've been googling to no avail, I have found answers like these:

[VS 2008 Windows Service Installer Doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148896/vs-2008-windows-service-installer-doesnt-work)

[Visual Studio missing "Add Installer" link in service project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407459/visual-studio-missing-add-installer-link-in-service-project)

[Adding a service installer and service process installer in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460686/adding-a-service-installer-and-service-process-installer-in-visual-studio)

[Easiest language for creating a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803)

But I cannot find it whatsoever.

Should look like :

[image]

But I get :

[image]

I see that Express does not have this option but I'm using VS2010 Professional and I have all other expected features.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, especially if it comes before I put my foot through my monitor.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: @Patrick Sorry but I don't understand your comment, no it isn't there, I have no option in VS to create it.  Thanks

Comment: @Patrick My question pertains to not having that option, yes I can add an Installer class manually.  Thanks

Comment: Can you build your project? Does your class that you are viewing in designer mode in fact inherit `ServiceBase`?

Comment: Can you create a new solution, add a service project and get the Add Installer in that project..?

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for your replies, Unfortunately I have already tried that, I'm thinking a fresh install is on the cards :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending too much time searching the interweb I decided to bite the bullet and simply perform a repair of VS 2010, this did take almost an hour but did solve the issue.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, thank you for your time and effort, it was appreciated.